# How can I represent video in avi format as a set of matrices using Java?

Tags: java, video, video-processing, video-encoding

I have a video in avi format and I would like to represent every frame of the video as a matrix using Java. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

The Java Media Framework might be a good place to start exploring. (Although it is a rather old API, I don't know of any other, better APIs for video processing with Java.)

[This](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-java-client-419417.html#7372-jmf-2.1.1e-oth-JPR) is the download page for the JMF

[Here](http://java.coe.psu.ac.th/Extension/JMF/jmf2_0-guide.pdf) is a good structured guide to the JMF.

And [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2se/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/2.1.1/apidocs/) is the API documentation for all the JMF classes.